# Disabling WPAD on windows 10

Tags: security, wpad

Slashdot just highlighted an article talking about the security hole of WPAD, and recommending that every computer have WPAD completely disabled: https://it.slashdot.org/story/16/08/13/0149241/disable-wpad-now-or-have-your-accounts-compromised-researchers-warn

After searching for how to disable, I found answers for Windows Server 2008 from 2013: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029615/how-to-turn-off-disable-web-proxy-auto-discovery-wpad-in-windows-server-2008

This seems like it is more important for this area than stackoverflow.  Are the instructions in this answer valid for Windows 10?  I do not want to blindly change registry entries without explicit knowledge that it is correct.  If not, what are the instructions to disable WPAD for Windows 10, and is there any way to write a script to automate it for many computers?

Comment: Registry modification works for Windows 10 as the keys are the same, maybe someone here can show you how to make a .reg file to merge into the registry on multiple machines.

Comment: Or "You don't need to mess around in the registry and reboot.

All you have to do is go into Internet Options (control panel) > Connections > LAN Settings

Uncheck the top box labeled Automatically detect settings."